# Why jcombobox is not visible?

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Dummy{
    String newSelection = null;

    public void init(){
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Something");
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        jFrame.setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        jFrame.setLayout(null);
        jFrame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        final String[] possibleNoOfPlayers = {"Two","Three"};

        final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(possibleNoOfPlayers);
        newSelection = possibleNoOfPlayers[0];
        comboBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,130));
        comboBox.setLocation(new Point(200,200));
        comboBox.setEditable(true);
        comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
        comboBox.setVisible(true);
        comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                JComboBox box = (JComboBox) actionEvent.getSource();
                newSelection = (String) box.getSelectedItem();
                System.out.println(newSelection);
            }
        });
        jFrame.add(comboBox);
    }
}
```

I am trying to add combo box to the frame. but it is not visible. if you click the position it will show the options. but it is not visible. Please let me know if i am missing something in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three things...

1. You've called `setVisible` on you frame BEFORE you added it
2. You're using `null` layouts
3. You've not set a size for the comobox, which will mean it will be (effectively) rendered as `0x0` size.  (ps- `setPreferredSize` is not doing what you think it should)...

Advisable solution...

Call `setVisible` last and use an appropriate layout manager

Answer (score 1):

use this one..

```
package oops;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class jframe extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                jframe frame = new jframe();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public jframe() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.setBounds(159, 81, 189, 41);
    contentPane.add(comboBox);
}
}
```

Comment: 1. Dumping code on unexpecting users is never particularly helpful without some explanation as to why. 2. `null` layouts are never a recommend solution when dealing with component based UIs...

Comment: yes he's using....JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Something");
                  jFrame.setVisible(true);
                  jFrame.setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
                 jFrame.setLayout(null);
                 jFrame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
it must be like this....JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Something");
                        jFrame.setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
                        jFrame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                        jFrame.setVisible(true);               jFrame.setLayout(null);

Comment: I know what the OP is using, it doesn't make it right nor should we be accepting their bad choices. While it's up to the OP to decide, we should, as professionals, offer guidance to best practices and techniques wherever possible, if they then chose to ignore them, it's at their peril - At least we won't need to deal with "some one said/recommended" questions...making the original answerer look bad in the process - IMHO

Comment: i was just practicing my oops concepts ...as i saw his questn in stackoverflow ...suddenly i created a new class for jframe to save my time to be the first answer but unfortunately ...you are become..:(